# How do I get the value from form input into a variable

Tags: javascript

Just started learning Javascript today and I'm stuck. The page just reloads when I submit.  Am I putting .value in the wrong place? Maybe some other noob mistake?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Calculate() {
        var volume = document.getElementById('volume').value;
        var carbonation = document.getElementById('carbonation').value;
        var temperature = document.getElementById('temperature').value;

        var sucrose = (15.195 * volume * (carbonation - 3.0378 + (0.050062 * temperature) - (0.00026555 * (temperature * temperature))))/28.4;
        var dextrose = sucrose + (sucrose * 0.15);

        document.write('<div id="result">You need ' + math.round(dextrose * 100)/100 + ' ounces of dextrose</div>');}
    </script>
    <form>
    <input id="volume" type="text">
    <input id="carbonation" type="text">
    <input id="temperature" type="text">
    <input type="submit" onclick="Calculate();" value="Calculate">
    </form>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Don't use submit. I think that type="button" is what you need.

Comment: I'm expecting whats in the document.write to be displayed on the page.  The page just refreshes :/

Comment: Submit will try to send data using HTTP POST method, use a button instead. Also, in your function, remove the last semicolon, some versions of IE don't like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submitting will happen before the function is executed, therefore the page will reload instead of running your function when you click that button.

Use an `<input type="button">` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put

```
return false;
```

At the end of your function so that the page doesn't reload.

Like this

```
function Calculate() {
    // All Code here...

}
```

This will prevent the form from being submitted.

And instead of attaching the click event you need to use the submit event

**Add ID to the form**

```
<form id="myForm">
```

**Listen for when the form is submitted**

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.onsubmit = Calculate;
```

And change your button to

```
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
```

Comment: @rid if the form doesn't go anywhere then why does it say in the question that the page is reloading? if you don't apply a `action` to the form it just uses the current page..

Comment: Actually, `<button>` also submits the form, i don't know about `<input type="button">` though....